# How to set sklearn CountVectorizer to include non-alphanumeric characters as the feature extraction?

Tags: regex, nltk, tokenize, feature-extraction, scikit-learn

By using NLTK whitespacetokenizer I am able to curate a vocabulary with non-alphanumeric terms but at the transform step those terms are not counted and they are 0 at all the feature vectors. Thus the problem is even I tokenized the docs with simple white space partition, I also need to change the tokenpattern of the CountVectorizer. However, I am unable to figure out which kind of regular pattern should I use? Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your confusion, it seems that what you need is to learn RegEx ([here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).

If you want the token to match everything, you can set the `token_pattern` attribute in `CountVectorizer` as:

```
.*
```

Meaning it will match every token coming from the tokenizer.

If you just want to match non-alphanumeric tokens, you can use:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]*
```